# How to use Spatial Criteria with ArcPy Data Access Search Cursor?

Tags: arcpy

The [ArcGIS documentation for the Data Access Search Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) states:

> The records returned by SearchCursor can be constrained to match attribute criteria or spatial criteria.

But I can't see any example of how to specify spatial criteria when calling the search cursor.  For this example I have a geometry and wish to constrain the results of the search cursor to only features which both intersect that geometry and meet other attribute criteria.  e.g.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,field_list,
                          "Admin_Code is null and shape intersects admin_area_geometry")
```

I understand that I could perform a search cursor with the attribute query and then use the geometry intersects method but this would be slow to have to loop through each feature.

How can I specify both the *spatial criteria* when creating a search cursor?

Comment: Can you expand more what you mean by "intersect that geometry".  Are you wanting to intersect two layers or one layer with itself?

Comment: It's two layers - I want to base an ID/admin_code on the intersecting polygon, but only need to identify those intersecting the input admin area where the admin_code is null - hence my reluctance to loop through all features.

Comment: I wonder if the documentation is simply alluding to using SelectLayerByLocation before arcpy.da.SearchCursor.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, that worked - I used select by location to give a combination of spatial + attribute condition. Hadn't realised the cursors now accept feature layers which I spotted in another of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a where clause to lessen the impact of pulling out geometry info that way you are not iterating through the entire table:

```
import arcpy

fc = 'c:/base/data.gdb/roads'
class_field = 'Road Class'
name_field = 'Name'

# Create an expression with proper delimiters
expression = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, name_field) + ' = 2'

# Create a search cursor using an SQL expression
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [class_field, name_field, SHAPE@],
                           where_clause=expression) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # continue with logic
```

Comment: Thanks - that's where I'm at but I'd also like to limit the search cursor with a spatial condition, as hinted at in the ESRI docs.. frustratingly this would be easy in SQL with ST_INTERSECTS but I'm finding it difficult to replicate in ArcPy..